# where is the Chef extension deployment log?

Tags: azure, chef-infra

I tried to install chef extension on my Azure VM using ARM following template in https://docs.chef.io/azure_portal.html

After the ARM deployment done. I could not find the node in chef server console, and cannot find chef folder on the Azure VM.

There is NO any error output during the ARM deployment. I have no idea what is wrong.

Where is the chef extension installation log on the VM?

Comment: While Chef related, this isn't really Chef specific. You would probably be better off asking on the Azure support forums.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the logs under `/var/log/azure/Chef.Bootstrap.WindowsAzure.LinuxChefClient/`